# Add function output to sidbar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add the output of function OplionList() to the sidebar

The sidebar opens but no output is present

I'm guessing the function OplionList() is not being read

Not sure what more details I can give

After hours of failed effort asking for assistance

Thanks

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Refresh')
      .addItem('Get Option List', 'displayOptionList')
      .addToUi();     
};


function displayOptionList(){
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('Option List');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);

};
```

Sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="OP"></div>
    <script>
       function OplionList() {
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
       var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
       var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, 3).getValues();
       values = values.filter(function(e){return e[0] && e[1] && e[2]});
       var result = [];

       //Add items to results
       for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){ // Modified
         result[i] = ["option {<br />label: \"" + values[i][1] + "\";<br />" + "selector: [\"" + values[i][0] + "\"=\"" + values[i][2] + "\"];<br />}<br />"];
       };

       var temp = ""
       for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){ // Modified
          temp = temp +  [result[i] + "\n"];
       };

       temp = "target: \" element \";<br />" +"as dropdown;<br />" + temp + "}"

       return temp

      };
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do your homework: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication If you want to run apps script code during templatization, you need to use scriptlets. If you want to run server code from client-side, you need to use `google.script.run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your script.

1)Your 'OplionList()' function is declared but not called. You still need to explicitly call the function (see below) or wrap your code in an immediately invoked function expression.

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <script>

   function myFunc(){
    console.log(5);
   }

   myFunc(); //calls the function

    </script>
  </body>
```

Or

```
<script>
 (function(){

   console.log(5);

  })();
```

2) Secondly, you can't directly call Apps Script functions from the client side. The client-side code is rendered by your browser while GAS code executes on Google servers, so the execution environment is not shared. Apps Script classes like SpreadsheetApp, DocumentApp, and others can't be magically transferred to your local browser program. That said, Google does provide a way of calling GAS functions using asynchronous JavaScript API.

Consider moving 'OplionList()' to the .gs file, call it from the client using google.script.run, and then inject the HTML string into the page using the client-side function. The output of the server function is passed as an argument to the 'withSuccessHandler' callback. Here's the simplest scenario for rendering the server-generated content inside a 'div':

```
<body onload="populateContainer()">
<div id="container">Loading...</div>
...
<script>
var container = document.getElementById("container");

function populateContainer(){

google.script.run
             .withSuccessHandler(function(html){
                  container.innerHTML = html;
              })
             .withFailureHandler(function(error){ console.log(error);})
             .OplionList(args);

}

</script>
</body>
```

More details on client-server communication in GAS https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Another method is using scriptlets to build your templates
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets

Be advised though that this will make your code run slower.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the Google Apps Script services classes and methods are available only as server-side code. More specifically, we can't use SpreadsheetApp on client-side code.

Regarding the OptionList function not been read, the client-side code doesn't include a call to that function.

Please checkout the guide on [Dialogs and Sidebars in G Suite Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs).